# visualstudio reference one project in many solutions located in different TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have my own TFS (visual studio online) and work TFS. In my TFS located my own projects and, in particular, the project with useful utilities. I want to connect it to the work TFS solution, but keep getting an error, which essentially boils down to the fact that you can not connect a project in more than one TFS. Can I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot use multiple Team Foundation Server instances at one time. When you switch a project, you switch to the TFS server that it's stored in.

The recommended way to share utility code like you're talking about is by sharing only the binaries. This can be done using NuGet. You can setup your own NuGet repository and then let your utility project publish to your NuGet server. Other projects can include your NuGet packages just as you use external packages.

You can find a great overview of what NuGet can do [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh547106.aspx).